# How to prevent duplicates in for each loop based on Rail associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been using Rails for awhile but am less familiar with what is possible with Ruby and am hitting a wall. I have a Books controller and Recommendations controller, and a book has_many recommendations. I'd like to create a list of the recommendations but without repeating a book.

This is basically what I have -

```
#Recommendations controller, index
@recommendations = Recommendation.all

#Recommendation view, index
@recommendations.each do |r|
  r.text
  r.book.cover_image
end
```

I tried going through Books and essentially running the each loop on all books, but then I had to essentially do @book.recommendation.first -- which means I wouldn't get to see all the recommendations.

Is there another way to do this that I'm not thinking of? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you post your desired output?  Do you need something like 'Moby Dick: 4 recs,' or do you just need to list the books?

Comment: @JoeEssey it should just be a list of the recommendation text (which will link to the book). So I don't need to refer at all to the book's other recommendations.

Comment: @Max's answer will get you that if you don't iterate over `@grouped_recommendations.recommendations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do the following:

- for every book that has at least one recommendation

  - list the book followed by its recommendations

There's a few ways you could do this. eg

```
#controller
@grouped_recommendations = Recommendation.include(:book).all.group_by(&:book)

#view
 @grouped_recommendations.each do |book, recommendations|
   book.cover_image
   recommendations.each do |recommendation|
     recommendation.text
   end
 end
```

Note that i'm missing out any formatting which you would of course need to include, i just copied the style of your question.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. i actually don't want multiple recommendations for each book, just one -- but not the same one every time. so i could possibly do something like this but with @random_recommendation in the controller so it does each book once but with a different recommendation each time?  It's confusing though, because if a book has a lot of recommendations, i do want it to show up more often, but just not right next to each other.

Comment: Instead of the `recommendations.each` block here, try `recommendations.sample.text`

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your controller, you can do:

```
@recommendations = Recommendation.includes(:book).all
```

So later on, inside of your view, when you do `r.book`, it will not query the database again.

Comment: so the view is @recommendations.each { |r| r.text } - which still seems to be repeating books with this.